# On what $BODY$ on postgresql trigger function is used for?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I've found some postgresql trigger tutorial. There is this example function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_log_trigg_function() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    account_type varchar;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'account_current') THEN
        account_type := 'Current';
        RAISE NOTICE 'TRIGER called on %', TG_TABLE_NAME;

    ELSIF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'account_savings') THEN
        account_type := 'Savings';
        RAISE NOTICE 'TRIGER called on %', TG_TABLE_NAME;

    END IF;

    RETURN null;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION add_log_trigg_function()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I know that `$BODY$` starts body function. But why it should named? Does this name `BODY` can or is usally used on other places? Besides `LANGUAGE`, `COST` and `ALTER FUNCTION` commands, what other commands usually stay outside `$BODY$`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

> A dollar-quoted string constant consists of a dollar sign ($), an
>   optional “tag” of zero or more characters, another dollar sign, an
>   arbitrary sequence of characters that makes up the string content, a
>   dollar sign, the same tag that began this dollar quote, and a dollar
>   sign.

In short - you can put any tag - not just `BODY` fro trigger or `function` for `\sf` as psql usually formats it. sample:

```
t=# do
$anything$
begin
 raise info '%', 'any tag would work';
end;
$anything$
;
INFO:  any tag would work
DO
```

also answering any it should be named - it should not.jut `$$` is same fine as `$BODY$`, but "naming" is very helpful when you need to use quoting inside quoting. like in my sample above I use single quote quoting with `raise`, and I don't need to double single quotes or escape them to use inside body, because I use dollar sign quoting already. probably the clearer sample would be:

```
t=# do
$anything$
begin
 raise info $$%$$, $someothertag$any tag would work$someothertag$;
end;
$anything$
;
INFO:  any tag would work
DO
```